# Trying to swap a model in my controller test with IoC Container, but object not swapper

Tags: php, laravel, mockery

I'm trying to use IoC Container to swap out my Question model when testing. Although I've created a mock model, and using App::instance() to attempt to swap the dependency during my test, I can see from `var_dump` that it isn't working. What is wrong with my code?

```
<?php

class QuestionsControllerTest extends TestCase {

    protected $mock;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // This is how Net tuts tutorial instructed, but 
        // I got Eloquent not found errors
        // $this->mock = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'Question');

        // so I tried this instead, and it created the mock
        $this->mock = Mockery::mock('App\Question'); 
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function testQuestionIndex()
    {
        // var_dump(get_class($this->mock)); exit; // outputs: Mockery_0_App_Question
        // var_dump(get_class($this->app)); exit; // outputs: Illuminate\Foundation\Application

       $this->mock
           ->shouldReceive('latest')
           ->once()
           ->andReturnSelf();

        $this->mock
            ->shouldReceive('get') //EDIT: should be get
            ->once()
            ->andReturn('foo');

    $this->app->instance('App\Question', $this->mock);


        // dispatch route

        $response = $this->call('GET', 'questions');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

So far so good? Below is my QuestionsController:

```
class QuestionsController extends Controller {

    protected $question;

    public function index(Question $question)
    {
        // var_dump(get_class($question)); exit; // Outputs App\Question when testing too

        $questions = $question
            ->latest()
            ->get();

        return view('questions.index', compact('questions'));
    }
    ...
```

So, without the object being swapped, it doesn't register anyway call to the methods:

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method latest() from Mockery_0_App_Question should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.
```

By the way, I've installed Mockery ~0.9, Laravel 5.0, and PHPUnit ~4.0. Would really really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with laravel or php unit testing so this comment may not be relevant, but I do not wire up dependencies using the IoC container for unit tests.  I would instead create an instance of `QuestionsController` directly and pass in the dependency.

Comment: Laravel test case class seems to have a lot of built in assertions for testing things such as variables that get passed to the view, status code returned etc, I can't imagine these being available with testing the controller independently of the app? I guess in a strict sense of unit testing this might work, I haven't used Laravel long enough. I'll try it out some time though if all else fails, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to specify the full namespace when using `instance()`. Laravel otherwise will assume the model is in the global namespace ('\Question').

This should work:

```
$this->app->instance('App\Question', $this->mock);
```

---

Now regarding the other problem, your mock. Since your view wants a collection why not just give it one? And if you don't want to test the view you can simply instantiate an empty collection and return that:

```
$this->mock
     ->shouldReceive('latest')
     ->once()
     ->andReturnSelf();

$this->mock
     ->shouldReceive('get')
     ->once()
     ->andReturn(new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection);
```

If you want you can also check if the view has correctly received the variable with:

```
$response = $this->call('GET', 'questions');

$this->assertViewHas('questions');
```

Comment: Hi thanks, this seems to pass in the object now but I'm now getting a 500 response, so my status assertion is failing. It's not giving me any error message other that `Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.`

Comment: Probably because you only specify that `latest()` should called and what it should return so calling `get()` on the result throws an exception. (see the other answer to this question) If you want to get more details about the error have a look at the log file in `storage/logs`

Comment: Yes. Seems and invalid variable for the foreach in the view as the mock item is returning not an instance of Eloquent\Collection but instead a string of "foo" :) Can I mock an Eloquent Collection? Or, disable the view rendering from the test? How shoul this be handled in controller tests? If I return "foo" it's going to break my view (e.g. foreach, properties etc).. anyway, slowly getting there, thanks

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, actually I should have through to do that myself. I was thinking I had to mock everything, but an empty collection will absolutely do. Anyway, all is working with my test. Bounty's yours. (UPDATE: It says I have to wait 3 hours for some reason, will award it then :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error as you didn't define your mock completely.

you told your mock that it should expect `latest` to be called once, but you did not specify what latest should return. on the next line in your controller you call `get`.

Try the following code

```
    $this->mock
       ->shouldReceive('latest')
       ->once()
       ->andReturnSelf();


     $this->mock
       ->shouldReceive('get') //EDIT: should be get
       ->once()
       ->andReturn('foo');

    $this->app->instance('Question', $this->mock);
```

Very good article about testing controllers in larvel http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-laravel-controllers--net-31456

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. Yeh I followed that article but it didn't work for me. As mentioned, when I output the get_class($question) in the controller when running the test, I can see that it isn't the mocked object. However, the previous poster suggested to use the full path `$this->app->instance('App\Question', $this->mock);` and this does pass the object, but I'm getting a 500 error now so my status code assertion is failing.